# Is there a typo in the statement of theorem 10.5.9.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

The statement of the theorem is:

[image]

But is there a typo in that $A \in \mathbb{R^n}$ instead of $A \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Also could anyone clarify for me the relationship between a set being in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{R^n}$, as I am confused about this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! This is not a typo. I'm assuming that, when defining $f$, it was specified that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. While we usually think of continuity as there being "no jumps" in the function, the definition you have is in fact more precise, and more useful. Indeed, we say a function is continuous whenever the preimage of an open set is itself open. In other words, a function $f$ is continuous if it preserves openness through preimages. But this is precisely what the definition you have states! You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces).

Also, to address the second question, a point in $\mathbb{R}$ is just a real number, as we traditionally think of them. $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as the set containing all possible lists of $n$ ordered real numbers. For example, $(0,\frac{2}{3},-\pi)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: what about my second question?

Comment: so the point 1 on the real line can not be expressed as (1, 0, ....., 0) in $\mathbb{R^n}$ ...... correct?they are totally different.

Comment: Yes, those points live in completely different spaces.